# Remove argument error from ListView Adapter in Android

Tags: java, android, listview

This is my code:

```
public class BusinessAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String[]> {
    private final Context context;
    String[] dataList;

    public BusinessAdapter(Context context,  String[] dataList) {
        super(context, R.layout.business_row,dataList);
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }
```

I am getting an error in super. It says that I must remove dataList from its arguments. So far, I am using the same code for creating ListView adapters and I didn't have any problem. Can you see any mistake?

I have cleaned the project but nothing changed.

Comment: I guess that 'dataList' is not null. Can you show us the entiere stacktrace ?

Comment: it is an error in build phase. And it writes what I wrote (remove argument). Weird thing is that this code is the same with other listviews I have implemented.

Comment: I don't see R.layout.business_row here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) the constructor you are calling wants as last argument an array of the generic type. In your case it wants an array of a string array. One possible solution would be to change your class to `... extends ArrayAdapter<String> {`. If that is not possible you could change the `BusinessAdapter` constructor to `public BusinessAdapter(Context context,  String[][] dataList)`.

Answer (score 1):

You adapter will contain a list of `String`so it should extends **ArrayAdapter<String>** not **ArrayAdapter<String[]>** !